# Count the number of each unique row in a data frame?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame such like:

```
df<-data.frame(x1=c(0,1,1,1,2,3,3,3),
x2=c(0,1,1,3,2,3,3,2),
x3=c(0,1,1,1,2,3,3,2))
df
  x1 x2 x3
1  0  0  0
2  1  1  1
3  1  1  1
4  1  3  1
5  2  2  2
6  3  3  3
7  3  3  3
8  3  2  2
```

what I want is to count the number of each unique row such like:

```
  x1 x2 x3 count
1  0  0  0  1
2  1  1  1  2
4  1  3  1  1
5  2  2  2  1 
6  3  3  3  2
8  3  2  2  1
```

What's the easiest way to realize it in R?

Comment: @Whuber, instead of putting it on hold, just migrate it to SO. It is a reasonable, well formatted and clear question asked on a wrong SE site. We can provide many other good answers there which future users can benefit from.

Comment: @David A Thank you for the suggestion.  I think you're right, but at the time (a) I saw there was an answer here and (b) I strongly suspected this very question has appeared on SO before.

Comment: @whuber, I didn't check for dupes, but I think the OP would still receive many more good answers. Either way, it seems they are good with `plyr` so that doesn't matter anymore I guess.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `count` function from the `plyr` package.

```
library(plyr)
df = data.frame(x1=c(0,1,1,1,2,3,3,3),
               x2=c(0,1,1,3,2,3,3,2),
               x3=c(0,1,1,1,2,3,3,2))

count(df, vars = c("x1", "x2", "x3"))
```

Output:

```
> count(df, vars = c("x1", "x2", "x3"))
  x1 x2 x3 freq
1  0  0  0    1
2  1  1  1    2
3  1  3  1    1
4  2  2  2    1
5  3  2  2    1
6  3  3  3    2
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code. I got: "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `vars` must be length 8 (the number of rows) or one, not 3"